# New line in Silverlight string resource

Tags: silverlight-4.0, resources, newline

how to add new line in my string resource file?

I already tried `\r\n`, `\n`, `&#13;`, `&#10;` but it displays exactly what you've indicated, it does not give a new line.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, but its a bit indirect. By using `&#13;` you could add a new line, the only trick here is that & gets converted to `&amp;#13;` in the background. To bring it back to `&#13;`, all you have to do is open your .resx the file in xml (right-click and open with XML (Text) editor), remove the `amp;` of the `&amp;#13;`

Before

```
  <data name="HelloWorld" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Hello &amp;#13; World</value>
  </data>
```

After

```
  <data name="HelloWorld" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Hello &#13; World</value>
  </data>
```

Answer (score 1):

When editing resource file in designer press Shift + Enter for new line.